# How can i print a database query to a javascript array?

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, database, drupal-7

I want to display some information in a [jvector map](http://jvectormap.com/tutorials/getting-started/) and get the information out of the database with these code:

```
$query = db_select('location', 'l')
    ->condition('l.lid', 0, '<>')
    ->fields('l', array('country'))
    ->range(0, 50);

$result = $query->execute();
$arr = [];

while($record = $result->fetchAssoc()) {
      $arr[] = $record;       
}
print_r($arr);
```

For the fields i use the location modul in Drupal 7 and i get these array:

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( 
        [country] => de 
    ) 
    [1] => Array ( 
        [country] => de 
    ) 
    [2] => Array ( 
        [country] => fr 
    ) 
)
```

But, how can i take out these information, count the countries and display it as a javascript display like: `var gdpData = { "de": 2, "Fr": 1, ... };` for the jvector map?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the wrapper function `drupal_json_encode` for Drupal 7.

Or alternatively, you can pass the PHP `$arr` variable to `drupal_add_js(array('locations' => $arr), 'setting');` and access it as follows in javascript:

`var gdpData = Drupal.settings.locations;`

Comment: Great Thanks! I use drupal_add_js(array('location' => array_count_values($arr)), 'setting'); and i get what i want:  Object { de=2, fr=1} very nice!

Answer (score 2):

[json_encode](http://php.net//manual/en/function.json-encode.php) — Returns the JSON representation of a value

```
json_encode($arr);
```

### Sample :

```
while($record = $result->fetchAssoc()) {
    if (isset($arr[$record["country"]])) {
        $arr[$record["country"]]++;
    } else {
        $arr[$record["country"]] = 0;
    }
}

json_encode($arr);
```

In javascript :

```
JSON.parse(data);
console.log(data.de); //2
```

Comment: Wow thanks, i try it as soon as possible! Why did you get an negative vote?

Comment: I don't know, my answer works ?

Comment: I'd warrant a guess for your -1 being somebody doesn't like your coding style, but I'll +1 because it works.

Comment: i get an error: SyntaxError: invalid arrow-function arguments (parentheses around the arrow-function may help)
[0] => de

Maybe i do something wrong: <script> <?php $output = drupal_json_encode(array_count_values($arr)); ?> JSON.parse($output); console.log($output.de); </script>

Comment: You mix php and js...